# compare dates using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date timestamp stored in mysql which is like `2017-06-29 08:37:31`

I am getting it through AJAX and I want to compare it with current date, whether it is same or not.

My code is

```
let dateStamp = moment(this.notificationData[0].notification_timestamp).format('LL');//date/timestamp from mysql received in json
let dateToday = moment().format('LL');//current date
console.log(dateStamp,dateToday)                            
console.log(moment(dateToday).diff(dateStamp,'days'))//comparison
```

Though I am getting the result in .diff(). I want to know if there is any other correct way of doing this.

Timezone is not an issue I think for me. Just date comparison.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to check whether two date is same or not you can also use `isSame` function. Here's the link https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/

Comment: You can directly compare it without formatting & finding difference. Just when you get moment object of dates compare like if dateStamp > dateToday

Comment: If you're only interested in an exact match you could quite easily just do a text comparison. No faffing around with parsing dates and all that!

Answer (score 1):

You can always write logic yourself and not depend on external libraries.

If you want to continue to use external logic, try out one of the libraries the momentjs team recommends. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

- [day.js](https://day.js.org/)
- [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)

If you want to write your own logic, try to use the `Date()` object.

```js
const now = new Date();

const dateString = now.toLocaleDateString();
const timeString = now.toLocaleTimeString();

// will create new date object with the timestamp
const dateFromApi = new Date(timestamp)
```

after that you are free to write whatever comparison logic you need.

Comment: yeah momentjs lib was abandoned because of some bad practices. There are better JavaScript date libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can compare them directly.

```
var date = moment("2017-07-11")
var now = moment();

if (now > date) {
   // date is past
} else {
   // date is future
}
```

You can also use isBefore, isSame, and isAfter.